# 2 network cards on ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, internet, dhcp

I am struggling getting this to work.
I have 2 network cards, eth0 is used for the local area network. The clients get DHCP from eth0 which is setup as a dhcp server on Ubuntu. There is no internet connection on eth0

Eth1 is where the internet connection is. The clients won't get any DHCP or be able to connect to eth1 at all but will only be used as an internet gateway for eth0. Similar to a proxy server

I have a screenshot of my interface file. When I stop and then start the networking service I get failed and only started failing when I entered in the eth1 details.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting. https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: You should have a look at the wiki about [connection sharing](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing)

Answer (score 0):

> The clients get DHCP from eth0 which is setup as a dhcp server on Ubuntu. There is no internet connection on eth0

Then *don't* specify a default gateway on that interface. According to your screenshot, you have configured 192.168.137.1 as default gateway for this interface - which means that you tell your computer that 0.0.0.0/0 (aka the rest of the Internet) is reachable via 192.168.137.1 - when it is in fact not reachable this way.

In addition you will have to set up some kind of forwarding or NAT for the clients connected to eth0 to be able to reach the internet via this box.